# Better way to give numbering to example

Tags: macros

Is there any other way to write examples with numbering in mathematics? I am using asmart class.

```
\textbf{Example 1 }
```

Comment: Use a theorem construction. Something like `\theoremstyle{definition} ` (just a name of the style) and then `\newtheorem{example}{Example} `, then the example env will number it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this style is what you want to achive, but here is a MWE showing how to use `\newtheorem` to get a numbered `example` environment that you can refer to with the usual `label` / `ref` approach:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
some example
\label{test example}
\end{example}
Reference the above example: \ref{test example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As stated by  barbara beeton  in the comments, the above example will number examples and theorems using the same counter. If you want to number the examples separately, use `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]` instead.

Comment: this will number the examples with the same series of numbers as any theorems.  if examples should be numbered separately, then specify `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]` instead.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an automatic numbering, a correct vertical spacing w.r.t. the context, use something like this:

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
......
\begin{document}
......
\begin{example}
......
\end{example}
......
\end{document}
```

The layout details can be customised with dedicated packages like `amsthm` or `ntheorem`, using one of their predefined `styles`. A package like `thmtools`, which cooperates with both, provides further possibilities of customisation.